# Сортировать записи в БД за последние 5 дней

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня есть в таблице поле с именем `post_date` с типом `datetime` содержимым `2021-02-14 12:38:24`. таких записей много, подскажите, как можно отсортировать записи за последние 5 дней. Я предполагаю вывести записи в массив и заняться перебором но предполгаю, что для таких целей придуман sql запрос

Comment: правильно предполагаете. какие есть идеи по составлению запроса?

Comment: еще надо подумать над тем что сортировка это например по возрастанию. а когда за последние5 дней это фильтрация, когда часть данных надо отсеять.

Comment: гугли сравнение дат и интервалы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544438/select-records-from-now-1-day

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, актуально или нет, но вот как вариант. `table` - это твоя таблица

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.post_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
ORDER BY t.post_date
```